# .Net Error - System.AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write protected memory

Tags: .net, asp.net, c

I am using server side active x control for paging (http://activexperts.com/xmstoolkit/). The code below worked find on windows 2003 servers but now we moved to windows 2008 and I am getting the following error:

> System.AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write protected
>   memory. This is often an indication
>   that other memory is corrupt. at
>   AXmsCtrl.PagerProtocolSnppClass.Clear()
>   at _Default.Button1_Click(Object
>   sender, EventArgs e) in
>   D:\Apps\pagetest\Default.aspx.vb:line
>   15

I've searched and read various threads but am not able to find solution. Thanks in advance for your help.

Here is the code:

```
Partial Class _Default
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
    Private objSnppProtocol As PagerProtocolSnpp = New PagerProtocolSnpp
    Private objPagerMessage As PagerMessage = New PagerMessage

    Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Try

            objPagerMessage.Clear()
            objPagerMessage.Recipient = "12345"
            objPagerMessage.Data = "Testing send page."

            objSnppProtocol.Clear()
            objSnppProtocol.Server = "111.111.11.11"
            objSnppProtocol.ServerPort = System.Int32.Parse("446")
            objSnppProtocol.ServerTimeout = 2000

            objSnppProtocol.ProviderPassword = "2125551212 2125551212"
            objSnppProtocol.LogFile = Server.MapPath("log.txt")

            ' Send
            objSnppProtocol.Send(objPagerMessage)
            UpdateResult(objSnppProtocol.LastError, objSnppProtocol.ProviderResponse)
        Catch exc As Exception
            Response.Write("<br><font color='maroon'><strong>Paging ERROR:</strong></font><br>" & exc.ToString() & "<br>Trace: " & exc.StackTrace.ToString())
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub UpdateResult(ByVal numResult As System.Int32, ByVal strResponse As String)
        ctlResult.Text = numResult.ToString() & ": " & objSnppProtocol.GetErrorDescription(numResult)
        ctlResponse.Text = strResponse
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: stay away from hungarian notation - MS recommended people stop that back in 2003 : )  no need for 'obj' on everything - everything is basically an object now. use a name to refer to its purpose. ex. instead of objSnppProtocol use snnpProtocol

Comment: OMG... I thought Access Violations were deprecated (never to be seen again) exceptions. Never even imagined some day I would discover such exception existed in .net. This is a sad day to me.

Comment: @Miguel - they basically are unless you do an unsafe operation, or deal with unmanaged code. You can still break via interop, bad marshalling, etc - but then you are crossing boundaries between native/managed code. In this case its an activex control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your component is crashing in unmanaged code - contact the vendor. - also are you trying to run this on a 64 bit system now for 32 bit code?

Comment: The new OS is 64 bit. We will contact the vendor.

Comment: The issue was that the wrong interop dll was being used on win 2008 server. When the active x control is installed it creates an interop dll that we place in the website bin folder. The problem was that when installed on my laptop (windows vista) it creates an interop dll that does not work on the staging server (win 2008). So basically on win 2008 staging server the interop dll from the sample sites folder needs to be copied to the website folder.